# I have written an scrollable image gallery in Tkinter Python. when number of images per row is 1 or 2 it shows the images with defects

Tags: python, image, tkinter, gallery, scrollable

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, ttk
import pyautogui
import cv2
import h5py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from numpy.linalg import norm
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time
from termcolor import colored
from Ham_Img_Analyzer import featHA
import threading
import time
import atexit
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import PhotoImage
class Timer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.seconds = 0
        self.time_str = ""

    def run(self):
        """A function to show a timer that updates every second."""
        
        while not self.stop_event.is_set():
        
            m, s = divmod(self.seconds, 60)
            self.time_str = "{:02d}:{:02d}".format(m, s)
            print(colored("Elapsed time: {}\r".format(self.time_str),"green"), end="")
            time.sleep(1)
            self.seconds += 1
        
             
    def start(self):
        self.stop_event = threading.Event()
        self.timer_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run)
        self.timer_thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.stop_event.set()
        self.timer_thread.join()

    def get_elapsed_time(self):
        return self.time_str


        


class ScrollableImageGallery(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.hscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.vscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.scrollable_frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        
        self.scrollable_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all")))
        
        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")
        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.hscrollbar.set, yscrollcommand=self.vscrollbar.set)
        
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both",expand=True)
        self.hscrollbar.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
        self.vscrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        
        self.load_images(image_index) # Replace with the path to your image folder
        
    def load_images(self, folder):
        # image_files = os.listdir(folder)
        images = []
        row_num = 0
        col_num = 0
        
        for image_path in image_index:
          
            image = Image.open(image_path)
            file=(image_path.split("\\")[-1])
            images.append((file, image)) # Add file name to tuple     
        for i, (file, image) in enumerate(images):
            image=image.resize((image_width,image_height))
            photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
            label = tk.Label(self.scrollable_frame, image=photo)
            label.image = photo
            label.grid(row=row_num, column=col_num, padx=0, pady=3)
            # title = tk.Label(self.scrollable_frame, text=file.split('.')[0])
            if 1<=image_number<=5:
                fontsize=10
            elif  6<=image_number<=7:
                fontsize=6
            elif 8<=image_number<=12:
                fontsize=4
            elif 13<=image_number<=16:
                fontsize=3
            elif 17<=image_number<=20:
                fontsize=2
            title = tk.Label(self.scrollable_frame, text=str(i+1)+"."+file,font=("Arial",fontsize))
        
            title.grid(row=row_num+1 , column=col_num) # Add title label below image label
            
            
            col_num +=1

           
            if col_num == image_number:
                col_num = 0
                # row_num +=image_number
                row_num +=2
            
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

image_number=1
screen_width,screen_height=pyautogui.size()
if image_number==None:
    image_number=5
image_width=((screen_width-120)//(image_number))-2
image_height=image_width*3//4           
if image_height>=screen_height:
    image_height=screen_height*3//4
f = open(r"C:\Users\VAIO\Desktop\DSC\Ham Model\Source_Image_paths_feather_path.txt", "r")
bank_path=f.readline().rstrip()
bank_path=bank_path[:-2]
feath_path=f.readline().rstrip()
f.close()



import glob
image_index=glob.glob(r"C:\Users\VAIO\Desktop\DSC\TEST_HAM\Image Samples\sample\*")
image_index=(image_index[:200])
 

         
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry(str(screen_width)+"x"+str(screen_height))
phot=PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\VAIO\Desktop\DSC\Ham Model\turtle.png")
root.iconphoto(False,phot)
root.title("*HamNet* Gallery")

scrollable_gallery = ScrollableImageGallery(root)
scrollable_gallery.pack(fill="both", expand=True)



root.mainloop()
```

I wanted to show 200 images

If i put image*number=2, i expect to show 2 images in every row. accordingly when imagenumber=1 i want to show 1 image in every row i . but for imagenumber=2 it shows images with defects after image 14 and it does not show all the images. for image*_number=*1  it shows images with defects after image 38 and it does not show all the images also. On the other hand, for  image*_number 3 to 20 it shows all the images correctly..

Comment: What is the size of the images for your case? May be the total height required to show all the images is too tall that exceed the limitation of what tkinter supports.  Try making the image a bit smaller or using pages instead.  I have no problem on displaying 200 images with size 400x300 and 3 images per row.

Comment: As you can see the code, the maximum size of the image_height is 3/4 of screen_height. And when ever image_number changes the image_width and image_height changes accordingly.

Comment: So the total height may be `150 x screen_height` which is around 150K for a FHD monitor.  That is over what tkinter supports.

Comment: That is not right, 3/4 is 0.75. For a full HD Monitor scren_height is 1080 and simple 3/4*1080 will be 810. please read more carefully!! I have written it shows all 38 first images correctly in image_number=1 and after image 38, it confronts problems!!

Comment: But you try to show 200 images, so it is 200 * 810 pixel.

Comment: It shows 200 images with resolution 1920*810 not resolution of 200*810. It does not relate to what tkinter supports. Tkinter supports 1920 *1080 if your hardware supports it. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Now, i guess you were right . i did not get what you meant the time you answered. Now, what is the solution?